# header position fixed on page scroll in Rdash Angular

Tags: css, angularjs, header

Hey I am using Rdash Angular Js. Is it possible to fix the header position on page scroll.

I tried something by `CSS` as below, but it didn't work for me.

```
.row.header{height:60px;background:#fff;margin-bottom:15px;top: 0;position: fixed;left: 250px;right: 0;z-index: 1030;color:#aaa;}
```

Comment: Hi, you use correct `position:fixed`, maybe the problem is in the class. Anyway you need to explain better your problem. If you can post a html in a snipper will be more easy answer to you.

Comment: hi i created the snippet [rdash-snippet](http://codepen.io/AhsanMughal/pen/NbPEQa) the header position is not fixed on scrolling.Original source of dashboard is [rdash-angular](http://rdash.github.io/#/). is there way to make header fixed by default.

Comment: @Ahsan Mustafa : can you please refer my answer?

Comment: `.row.header{height: 60px;
background: #fff;
margin-bottom: 15px;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;}`

I have try this and work. Try to add this in Line 18 on your codepen.

Comment: @jigar7521 thank you for your answer.

Comment: @MarcoRomana - Studio IGS thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

change this in your code pan :

```
    .row.header {
    height: 60px;
    background: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Or

can you please follow this link and get your things done , i have already given one answer regarding this in past : [Relevent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216701/sticky-header-table-in-angular-with-ui-scrollfix/40217014#40217014)

Or you can follow this link for other alternative soluiotn : [Other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251674/center-header-element-with-position-fixed-to-top-of-page?rq=1)